# Bulk import list csv of computer in a AAD group in Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, import, azure-powershell, bulk

I receive a CSV files that contains computers serial numbers and I have to add them to a AAD group in Azure.

I tried with the classic bulk import, ***Member object ID or user principal name [memberObjectIdOrUpn] Required***, but I don't know which parameter I should use instead serial number or computer name.

Or someone know how to deal it with powershell ?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for PowerShell way then you might have to go with [Add-AzureADGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/add-azureadgroupmember?view=azureadps-2.0) cmdlet. Regarding the question if you have to use serial number or computername, I believe you have to provide the Object's ID as RefObjectId parameter of [Add-AzureADGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/add-azureadgroupmember?view=azureadps-2.0) cmdlet accepts ID of the object.

To find the object ID's of devices, you can leverage [Get-AzureADDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaddevice?view=azureadps-2.0) cmdlet.

Related references:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0#devices
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/groups-bulk-import-members